UncategorizedMongoDbException
Getting the below error while upgrading mongo driver to 5.00 in spring java application
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Server at 127.0.0.1:27217 reports wire version 5, but this version of the driver requires at least 6 (MongoDB 3.6).; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoIncompatibleDriverException: Server at 127.0.0.1:27217 reports wire version 5, but this version of the driver requires at least 6 (MongoDB 3.6).

Different solution says its because my java application wire version(6) requires a higher version than my server(5). Tried to configure the MongoDB Java driver to use a lower maximum wire version of Server using compressorList()
compressorList(Arrays.asList(MongoCompressor.createZlibCompressor())) or SNAPPY
but its not wowrking. Any thoughts please ?
Tried to configure the MongoDB Java driver to use a lower maximum wire version of Server using compressorList()
compressorList(Arrays.asList(MongoCompressor.createZlibCompressor())) or SNAPPY
but its not wowrking.

Check the compatibility table at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/current/compatibility/
Java driver 4.8+ will not work with MongoDB older than 3.6.
You will need to either upgrade your MonogDB instance or downgrade your driver.

Thank You Joe. Will check with the team on this

Hi @Joe our MongoDB is older than 3.6, its 5.6 or something so ideally it should work right?

You might want to check on that.  MongoDB version 5.0.6 supports up to wire version 13: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/r5.0.6/src/mongo/db/wire_version.h
